# Pull Syslog from the server using Groovy in Jira

Tags: groovy, database-connection, jira, syslog

I am new to Groovy in Jira, and I am trying to pull syslogs off a certain database. I am wondering if anyone can put me to the right direction. I am using the script console to implement this.

I am guessing it will be on the local host. I am given these to access the database server  :

-Database server with Port Number
-Database name
-Password
-Application Database User
-Syslog Servers

Are there any tutorials I can use to be able to connect to the database server

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0):

Groovy provides the [Sql](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html) class to simplify connecting to JDBC data sources. Here's an example.

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

def jdbc = 'jdbc:h2:mem:'
def db = Sql.newInstance(jdbc, 'org.h2.Driver')

def foos = db.rows('select foo from bar')
...
db.close() // Done with connection
```

The driver and JDBC connection string depends on the DBMS you're connecting to (MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc).

## PostgreSQL example

Here's how to connect to PostgreSQL. The code below uses Groovy's Grape to download dependencies.

Note: `@GrabConfig` is required to load the `org.postgresql.Driver` class in a way that allows jdbc to find it.

```
@Grab('org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41')
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)

import groovy.sql.Sql

def host = '192.168.1.1'
def port = 5432
def dbname = 'foo'
def user = 'xxx'
def password = 'yyy'
def jdbc = "jdbc:postgresql://${host}:${port}/${dbname}"
def db = Sql.newInstance(jdbc, user, password, 'org.postgresql.Driver')
```

Comment: would you be able to identify which is which? like where do I put the database server, port, username, password etc? thank you

Comment: Only if i know which database management system you're connecting to.

Comment: I added a postgresql example.

Comment: I have tried this. But I am getting this error: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during conversion: No suitable ClassLoader found for grab....... also what does @Grab('org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41') do?

Comment: and i am using the script console on jira

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Maybe the Jira script console uses Gradle to handle dependencies. If that's the case, then use that rather than @Grab, which is Groovy's built-in dependency management. I don't use Jira, so I can't be of much help with it.